# Create Dynamically Allocated Array with Pointers to Structs C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

So I currently have a simple struct (linkedlist) that I will be using in a HashMap:

```
struct Node {
    std::string key, value;
    Node* head;
}
```

I'm currently trying to dynamically allocate an array with pointers to each struct. This is what I have right now ...

```
Node* nodes = new Node[100]
```

I understand this allocates an array of 100 nodes into memory (which I will have to delete later on); however, upon iteration to try to transverse these nodes (which I an implementing as a linked list)...

```
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    Node current = nodes[x]; // Problem is I wanted an array to node pointers. This is not a pointer.
    while (current != nullptr) { // this isn't even legal since current is not a pointer.
        // DO STUFF HERE
        current = current.next; // This is not a pointer access to a method. I'm looking to access next with current->next;
    }
}
```

Hopefully I was clear enough. Can someone how to allocate a dynamic array of pointers to structs? So far I'm able to dynamically allocate an array of structs, just not an array of pointers to structs.

Comment: Basically, by providing contiguous memory for your nodes, you're blowing up the whole link-list idea. There's no need for next node since you have spacial information (i.e., index)

Comment: You seem to not be certain whether you want a linked list or a dynamic array.

Comment: The idea was that I'm implementing a hashmap, therefore needing a dynamically allocated array of LinkedLists.

Comment: @Xari this clear things up, you should edit your question. And please don't describe the problem in comments, nobody reads comments :)

Comment: Done. Thanks for reminding me. I just stumbled upon this declaration ... Node** nodes = new Node*[100], which apparently creates a dynamic array with pointers to my nodes. Is this correct?

Comment: @Xari yes this is correct. However, not recommended. I'd use a vector instead.

Comment: I understand; however the requirement for this project was to avoid using vectors. Thanks so much for your confirmation though.

Comment: @Xari So create your own simple vector class and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches. Either you allocate an array of structures and introduce one more pointer that will point to the element in the array that will play the role of the head.

For example

```
Node *head = nodes;
```

(in this case head points to nodes[0])

After the list will not be needed you have to delete it using operator

```
delete [] nodes;
```

Or you can indeed to allocate an array of pointers to the structure like this

```
Node **nodes = new Node *[100];
```

But in this case each element of the array in turn should be a pointer to a dynamically allocated object;

And to delete the list you at first have to delete each object pointed to by elements of the array for example in a loop

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) delete nodes[i];
```

and then to delete the array itself

```
delete [] nodes;
```

It is a good idea to initialize each element of the array with zeroes when the array is allocated for example

```
Node **nodes = new Node *[100]();
```

Comment: In the event of the second one, which I will be implementing, upon deleting it would I do delete[] nodes or delete[][] nodes?

Comment: @Xari you'll need a for loop to delete each node. And then `delete[]` to delete the "container"

Comment: @Xari Whether you will need to delete each object pointed to by elements of the array depends on how you will write the function or destructor that frees the list. Or you manually need to delete each object pointed to by the array elements using delete. And then the whole array must be deleted using delete [].

Comment: Thank you guys so much for clearing things up. It made things a lot clearer. Especially with the new Node*[100]. It makes so much sense now.

Comment: In this line: Node **nodes = new Node *[100]() would this mean that the variables inside the struct will be initialized to 0? If so, what would the variable "Node* head" be in this scenario?

Comment: @Xari It is an array of pointers. So only pointers are initialized by zero. If you will declare an array of structures then data members of structures will be zero initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested you this structure:

```
class myList {

struct Node {
string value;
Node* next;
}

/*Public methods .. Add/Set/Get/Next/isEmpty.. etc ... */
Node* head, *tail;
};
```

in main:
`myList* lis = new myList[number];`
then you have number of lists! and do all work in class by method's and operators, like if you want the next node just call `lis[0].getNext();`
if you want to skip current node do`lis[0].Next();` ... etc ..

this how to work, what you try to do is looks like C program!